# Nested Form Rails Mass Assign issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I can't seem to have nested form working and I either don't see it or don't understand it. Here the error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: location
```

Now here how i wrote my

Model/Events:

```
#Data
  attr_accessible :customer_id, :description, :location_attributes
#Relationship
  has_many :locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true
```

Model/Locations:

```
#Data
  attr_accessible :address, :customer_id, :event_id, :latitude, :longitude
#Relationship
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :event
```

Controller:

```
  def create
    @event = current_customer.events.build(params[:event])
    ...
```

View:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :location do |e| %>
    <%= e.hidden_field :longitude %>
    <%= e.hidden_field :latitude %>
  <% end %>
```

Params

```
 "location"=>{"longitude"=>"-80.9449995",
 "latitude"=>"46.435371599999996"},
```

I am on rails 3.2.9 and hosted on a vps server. Now I don't understand why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should be, and note the plural:

```
<% f.fields_for :locations do |location_form| %>
```

This is because you're rendering fields for the locations objects which are associated with your form object. This will automatically make the parameters for these fields named `location_attributes`, so that they are then passed to your controller as such, and your model would then accept them.

Comment: Thank you that solve the issues but now for some reason locations doesnt get created